# Can we create temporary table somewhere other than in tempdb in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

This is the question have been asked in one of my interview.

Is it possible to create a temporary table someplace other than `tempdb` in SQL Server?

Comment: Technically, no. However. you can create a regular table in any database, including tempdb, and drop if afterwards for temporary use.

Comment: `tempdb` is the database that holds temporary tables, not a table itself, but I'm assuming you're just misremembering the exact phrasing.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "temporary table". If you mean when using a statement such as `CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID int);`, then no, that is a true temporary table and will be created in TempDB. You can however create staging tables (which some people refer to as temporary tables for some unknown reason), and those you can create where ever you like. I doubt, however, that was the aim of the question, and most likely, the simple answer is the obvious one: "No".

Answer (score 0):

**No** you can not.

If the interviewer asking about `temp tables` (regardless local or global ), the answer is No.

If he asked about workaround, you can create `Table Variables`, and for getting the difference between SQL Server temporary tables and table variables, go to [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1556/differences-between-sql-server-temporary-tables-and-table-variables/).